# Android not accessing different language files

Tags: android, file, android-drawable

In my drawable folder, I have several files that are written in Russian.

I have a program that iterates through the files inside the folder and saves their ids for future use. I tested it, it works, but it skips files that are written in Russian. How can I make Android recognize those files?

Comment: change your mobile language to russian and try again.

Comment: The phone does't have the option. Plus, if I'm deploying the picture, I don't want all the phones to do that.

Comment: as far as I know, the localized string resources should be place in values-xx , not in drawable ? right? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It is a picture. xxxxxxxx.jpg, where x's are all Russian letters. And it skips the file when reading it.

Comment: ah, I understand your problem now. Can you check the generated R file, drawable class? Can you see the constant whose name is same as your picture file ?

Comment: Yes, then you can't access it because it's not understood when compiling.
You may want to:
1/ Use another way of naming 
2/ Ask for reason why Russian character in name can't be compiled.
Good luck ;)

Comment: I thought that is what my question asked...